# delay in dynamic loading of external Javascript(JSON) file for Phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

im trying to load a external js (json) file (PhoneGap app) whose structure is like

```
   var localString ={
  "tag1": "Username",
  "tag2": "Password",
  "submit": "Submit"
   }
```

and using the below code to load it at runtime, the newlocale variable holds the name of the file to be loaded for eg: if locale is english-USA then var resourcePath = en-US.js. The issue is the first time i run this code i get this error "ReferenceError: localstring is not defined" , but it loads the external strings the second time i load it. In between i am calling the external file using "select" tag in html5. Can someone provide some insights on where im going wrong or any pointers to overcome this issue.

```
var newlocale = window.DeviceCulture.get();
local(newlocale);

function local(lang) {
try {
    var resourcePath = lang + '.js';
    var scriptEl = document.createElement('script');
    scriptEl.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptEl.src = resourcePath;
    alert(resourcePath);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptEl);
    //$('head').append(scriptEl);

    //var localString = window.localString;
    document.getElementById("07").value = localString['submit'];
 } catch (e) {
    errorEvent(e);
}
}
```

Comment: There is not enough info to answer your question. Where do you load localString?

Comment: Its in the same folder where my js file is present , all the code files are in the same folder(dir).

Comment: Can someone please guide on how to rectify this issue !!!

Comment: It appears that localString is not loaded by the time you get to the local() function. Hard to tell without seeing more code.

Comment: Hi Simon this is the only code i am using in my .js file, except for the calling lines :

var newlocale = window.DeviceCulture.get();
local(newlocale);

are a part of init() function which are executed first at runtime, then the function local(lang) is called. I am able to fetch the locale of the system properly at runtime but the localString does not load.

Comment: Ah heck, I see what is going on now. Let me give you a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I believe the root cause of your problem is that you are appending the tag for the .js file into the head after the page is already loaded. When you first load a page the script tages are downloaded and interpreted in order so b can depend on a. However, the way you are doing it is non-blocking so that the script you load is not fully loaded by the time you get to the next line in your code which tries to access "localString".

To solve this I'd restructure your code somewhat. First forget about making local files JavaScript. Just make them plain text .json files. For example:

```
{
    "tag1": "Username",
    "tag2": "Password",
    "submit": "Submit"
}
```

Then I'd load that file using XHR instead of script tag insertion. Something like:

```
var newlocale = window.DeviceCulture.get();
var localString;
local(newlocale);

function local(lang) {
    try {
        var resourcePath = lang + '.json';
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", resourcePath, true);
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0) {
                    localString = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    // at this point localString is loaded with the new language
                    document.getElementById("07").value = localString['submit'];
                }
            }
        }
        request.send();
     } catch (e) {
        errorEvent(e);
    }
}
```

and that should take care of things.

Comment: Thanks Simon , But i am doing this completely on the client side . So i have my files on the client side itself and not getting it from the server.

Comment: This will work from the client side. You can do an XHR to something in your assets directory. That lang.json path actually expands to file:///android_asset/www/lang.json for instance. Try it :)